# MultipleObjectsReturned - django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

get() returned more than one Malwares -- it returned 2!

Is the error that i'm getting whilst trying to write and run some lovely django code.

It appears to be triggered by the following command

```
Malwares.objects.update_or_create(name=name)
```

What am I doing wrong here! I'm happy to provide more code from other parts of the program if that will aid in resolution of this issue.

edit:

probably messed up the database at some point and that was what was causing the error, fixed by truncating the database and allowing it to repopulate

Comment: The `update_or_create` expects there to be exactly 0 or 1 items in the database. In your case, there are two objects with `name=name`, so you get the error. How to fix it depends on what you want to happen if there are zero or multiple matching items in the database.

Comment: try `Malwares.objects.filter(name=name).count()`

Comment: Nevermind, i probably borked something in the database as I managed to fix this by dropping the database and allowing it to repopulate.